# Optimal Quantity of Training Data for Fine-Tuning an LLM: Is Bigger Always Better?

Tags: natural-language-processing, gpt, large-language-models, language-model, fine-tuning

I am currently working on fine-tuning an LLM for a specific task, and I am trying to determine the optimal size for my training dataset. Intuitively, one might think that the more data, the better. However, I am aware that in some contexts, this may lead to overfitting or other issues.

What is the general consensus on the optimal quantity of training data required for fine-tuning a Large Language Model? Is bigger always better?

Comment: Are you pretraining or fine-tuning?

Comment: Fine-tuning a pretrained model to get better on a task.